Algorithmically check if there is a line avoiding obstacles
I came up with the following question when coding a turn-based game with grid map, but after thinking a while it looks like a Computational Geometry question, so here it is.
In $\mathbb{R}^3$, with the standard coordinate system, consider all (say, open) unit cubes that have integer vertex points. I am given two such cubes $A$ and $B$, and another finite list of such cubes $C_i$. I want to check if there is any $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that the distance from the line segment $ab$ to any $C_i$ is positive. How to do this?
Consider this a mathematical problem, i.e. I want a deterministic algorithm that outputs the correct answer on all inputs, so no approximation is allowed, and hopefully one can use only integer calculations. And I also don't quite care about the time or space complexity of the algorithm.
I solved the problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$ case, but I cannot generalize it to $\mathbb{R}^3$ case.
Solution for $\mathbb{R}^2$ case. We first check if there is $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that the line segment $ab$ does not intersect any $C_i$ (so it might pass by the edge or vertex of some $C_i$, having distance $0$ but not intersecting). Let's denote this condition $P$. Take any line segment satisfying $P$, by pushing and rotating it, it remains a line segment satisfying $P$ until you hit vertices of $A,B,C_i$. So if there is any such line segment, there will also be one passing through two vertices of $A,B,C_i$. There are finitely many such combinations, so you can go through each of them and see if any satisfies this condition.
Then for each such line segment, you can check if you can modify it to have positive distance (rather than $0$ distance) to the $C_i$: you check all the cube vertices that lay exactly on this line segment. For each such vertex, you check the corresponding cube and it will give you a unique tangential direction along which you can safely move this line a little bit while maintaining $P$. Then overall you can do the modification if this tangential direction changes only onces along this line segment. See figure 1, where $A$ and $B$ are red, and the purple segment is one satisfying $P$ which can be modified a little bit (rotating counterclockwise) so that is has positive distance to each $C_i$, therefore the answer to the question is yes. In case of figure 2, it can no longer be modified, and the answer to the question is no.
Obstacle when generalizing to $\mathbb{R}^3$ case. I can still push or rotate a line segment, until I reach an edge $E$ of a cube. I can then push or rotate along $E$, and I will either hit another edge, or hit a vertex of $E$ (for simplicity count this as hitting another edge of the same cube). So I can check through all the combinations of "a cube vertex and two cube edges such that the 3 objects are not on the same plane", finitely many, and each of them uniquely determines a line. But then how to check if any of them can be safely modified to have positive distance? In $\mathbb{R}^3$ there is no such simple "tangential direction", and I got stuck here.
Does anyone have any idea on this? Or a fresh new solution is also welcomed.
Figure 1: https://i.sstatic.net/gCGqqjIz.png
Figure 2: https://i.sstatic.net/tX93Ryf0.png
